# No Smooth Onto Map from Circle to Torus

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

My professor was lecturing today and he made this statement which I was unable to verify. 
(I worded it nicer)

There is no map which is both smooth and onto from $S^1$ to $S^1$$\times$ $S^1$.

When he said this he included the original "one can clearly see" statement which is usually when the most people seem to be confused in his class.  Thus, I was hesitant to ask why.  So, please no one lecture me on the fact that I should have asked anyway.  If it is really that obvious, I would rather look stupid here than in class :)

Comment: I am increasingly becoming of the opinion that the phrase "clearly ____ is true" should be forever removed from mathematicians' vocabularies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This follows from [Sard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem), which implies that the image of a smooth map $S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ has Lebesgue measure zero. More generally, Sard's theorem implies that there are no smooth onto maps from a smooth manifold of dimension $n$ to a smooth manifold of dimension $m > n$.

The obvious statement is that there are no *diffeomorphisms* between such manifolds, which just follows by computing differentials (the differential of a diffeomorphism is an isomorphism). The differential of a surjective smooth map is not surjective in general (consider the surjection $\mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto x^3 \in \mathbb{R}$) so the obvious argument doesn't work (or at least it doesn't obviously work).

Note also that this statement is false if "smooth" is replaced by "continuous" due to the existence of [space-filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).

Comment: Ah good point.  I figured it fell out easily from some theorem. I just couldn't think of what theorem.  Remembering Sard's then does make the statement obvious.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

A smooth map $S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ is a differentiable curve; by differentiability it must have finite arc length. But a curve of finite length can't cover the 2-dimensional torus.

Comment: Why not? ${}{}$

Comment: You could, for example, consider dyadic points up to a certain scale, and notice that any path that goes through all of them must have a minimum length. Then take the scale to be sufficiently fine.