# Smooth map $S^1 \to S^2$ can not be surjective

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Why cannot a smooth (or piecewise linear) map $S^1 \to S^2$ be surjective?  There are [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), but the usual examples have very "twisty" definitions.

**UPD** A bit of background for this problem. It's part of he proof that all the normal vector fields on $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ are homotopic. Once it's proved that every map $S^1 \to S^2$ is homotopic to piecewise linear or smooth that is what is left to prove the statement.

**UPD** One more thing. This is a first semester set of tasks. Sard's theorem is not exactly what gives intuition besides this problem. Given answer for PL is what I was looking for. ;) It would be great to find a reasoning like this for the smooth case.

Comment: Does piecewise linear mean continuous in this context?

Comment: The proposals to close this as off topic are absurd. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Why? No effort is shown.

Comment: @Michael You are perfectly right and unfortunately I have noticed that analogous  proposals occur with unpleasant frequency. Especially for advanced topics in which most  closers probably have no clue. I wrote about that in Meta and my post got closed and deleted :-)

Comment: @avid19 There is no obvious way to show an effort in exactly this problem. If it was not clear it's all about statement that all normal vector fields on $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (and higher) are homotopic.

Comment: @StanO. for future reference, you would show effort/provide background by either telling us any thoughts you've had about the problem, fruitful or not, or giving us some sense of how much topology and differential topology you know.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I updated the question with details. Thank you for reply - that's a great idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Smooth Onto Map from Circle to Torus](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329115/no-smooth-onto-map-from-circle-to-torus)

Comment: @1999 Please read the answer by Kevin Carlson. This is what matters here (at least at the PL part).

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of Sard's theorem (see [wikipedia][1]). Namely, the critical values of a map $f:S^1 \to S^2$ are a null set in $S^2$. At a point, the derivative is a linear function from a $1$ dimensional vector space to a $2$-dimensional vector space, so every point in the image is a critical value.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem

Comment: @PVAL I really encourage you to read the answer to this question. Using Sard's theorem for this sort of first semester exercises is a bit over the top giving not too much to understanding of the geometry of the problem

Comment: Well Sard's theorem was the first theorem I learned in a one-semester differential topology course I took (i.e. pre- inverse function theorem) . It is also in the first chapter of Guilleman and Pollack. I am unlikely to be persuaded that is "a bit over the top".

Comment: @PVAL Well, in fact to be honest I forgot about it when was solving these exercises :) But anyway the answer for PL looks great. What solution was meant by my professor I will know in about two weeks when I meet him. This small question attracted a bit of attention at this forum. Quite unexpectedly :) Anyway if there will be some other interesting solution I will post it here.

Comment: @StanO.: Sard's theorem *is* the analogue of the PL answer given below. The point of that answer is essentially that a single linear lower-dimensional simplex has measure zero, and you're taking the union of these measure zero things. You are not going to show that the image of a smooth curve in $S^2$ is nowhere dense without it.

Comment: @avid19 : That's another reason why one should be able to click on something other than "off topic" for questions closed for lack of effort. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier for a PL map than a smooth one: the image of a PL curve lies in finitely many great circles. But no topological space is the union of finitely many nowhere dense sets (or for an unnecessarily big hammer use the Baire category theorem.)